# How to use subquery in SELECT clause?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, reportviewer

I have two table in my database main_item_stock and stock_history

I want to create a report to show that how many stock in, stock out and wastage for each item in main_item_stock, for every action that user do will insert a record into stock_history.

```
main_item_stock
-----------------------------------------------
stkitm_id  stkitm_code  stkitm_name  stkitm_qty
-----------------------------------------------
    1        S001         Apple        10.000
    2        S002         Orange        5.000
-----------------------------------------------


stock_history
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
stkhis_id  sktitm_id  stkitm_code  stkitm_name  stkhis_type  stkhis_qty  created_date
    1          1         S001         Apple       Wastage      1.000     2017/03/13
    2          2         S002        Orange      Stock Out     0.500     2017/03/12
    3          2         S002        Orange      Stock In      0.100     2017/03/13
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Result that I want:-

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
stkitm_code  stkitm_name  created_date  item_onhand  item_stockin  item_stockout  item_wastage
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   S001      Apple        2017/03/13    9.000        0             0              1
   S002      Orange       2017/03/12    4.500        0             0.500          0
   S002      Orange       2017/03/13    4.600        0.100         0              0

*item_onhand = main_item_stock.stkitm_qty
```

I have tried below query but stockin,stockout,wastage always return same value

```
query = "SELECT main_item_stock.stkitm_code,main_item_stock.stkitm_name,main_item_stock.stkitm_qty,
                    (SELECT SUM(stkhis_qty) FROM stock_history WHERE stkhis_type = 'Stock Out'"

            If dtp_from.Checked Then
                query &= " AND DATE(stock_history.created_date) >= '" & Format(CDate(dtp_from.Text), "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'
                           AND DATE(stock_history.created_date) <= '" & Format(CDate(dtp_to.Text), "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"
            End If

            query &= ") AS 'item_stockout',
                     (SELECT SUM(stkhis_qty) FROM stock_history WHERE stkhis_type = 'Wastage'"

            If dtp_from.Checked Then
                query &= " AND DATE(stock_history.created_date) >= '" & Format(CDate(dtp_from.Text), "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'
                           AND DATE(stock_history.created_date) <= '" & Format(CDate(dtp_to.Text), "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"
            End If

            query &= ") AS 'item_wastage',
                     (SELECT SUM(stkhis_qty) FROM stock_history WHERE stkhis_type = 'Stock In'"

            If dtp_from.Checked Then
                query &= " AND DATE(stock_history.created_date) >= '" & Format(CDate(dtp_from.Text), "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'
                           AND DATE(stock_history.created_date) <= '" & Format(CDate(dtp_to.Text), "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"
            End If

            query &= ") AS 'item_stockin'
                    FROM main_item_stock
                    LEFT JOIN stock_history
                    ON main_item_stock.stkitm_id = stock_history.stkitm_id"

            query &= " GROUP BY stock_history.stkitm_id"
```

How can I change the query and get the result that I want?

UPDATE:

I have tried another query, this time the return data is correct but can I use this table to create the report that I want?

```
SELECT SUM(stkhis_qty),stkitm_name,stkhis_type,DATE(created_date)
FROM stock_history
WHERE DATE(created_date) >= '2017/03/12'
GROUP BY stkitm_code,stkhis_type,DATE(created_date)
```

result:-

[image]

[image]

How can I changed image1 table to image2? The report need to have all these column

UPDATE:

This is main_item_stock

[image: main_item_stock]

This is stock_history

[image: stock_history]

Result should look like picture below, both type also can.

[image]

*the last record date on the picture is wrong should be 3/17/2017

Comment: Yes, why wouldnt you be able to? If you are using the reportviewer then after you query your data, put that data into a datatable and use it with the reportviewer control.

Comment: @codeMonger123 I know I can use a DataTable to create a report, but I dunno how to change StockOut,StockIn,Wastage to column

Comment: Do you want the report to be sorted by the item_id or by the history id? So `stkhis_id` or `sktitm_id` (first all apples, then all oranges, or not)? Depending on that, there are very different approaches possible.

Comment: @Solarflare I think I need sorted by created_date first then stkitm_id then only stkhis_id

Comment: I just saw your update. Does your history table really contains the `stkhis_onhand`-column? This would then actually be a completely different question than before, since you don't need to calculate it, just display it. Also your 2nd resulttype (the one with 11 rows instead of 6) is a simple pivot. It will look similar to what Tim wrote in his 2nd part, your 1st resulttype is a little more complicated. So if you are fine with your 2nd result example, a pivot can be used, even without a `sum()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you pretty close...

*edited to reflect the change of items on hand rather than the current total number of items on hand.

```
SELECT
sh.stkitm_code,
sh.stkitm_name,
SUM(IF(stkhis_type = 'Stock In', 
    sh.stkhis_qty, 
    -1 * sh.stkhis_qty))               AS change_of_item_onhand,
SUM(IF(stkhis_type = 'Stock In', 
    sh.stkhis_qty, 
    0))                                AS item_stockin,
SUM(IF(stkhis_type = 'Stock Out', 
    sh.stkhis_qty, 
    0))                                AS item_stockout,
SUM(IF(stkhis_type = 'Wastage', 
    sh.stkhis_qty, 
    0))                                AS item_wastage,
sh.created_date
FROM stock_history sh
LEFT JOIN main_item_stock mis ON mis.stkitm_code = sh.stkitm_code
WHERE sh.created_date > "<Oldest date>" 
AND sh.created_date < "<Youngest date>" 
GROUP BY stkitm_code
```

Which should result in output that looks like:

[image]

Although you'd probably want to group by the stkitm_code and date.

Alternatively, removing the "SUM"s and "GROUP BY" will itemize it, but the `item_onhand` column won't be cumulative (there might be a slick way to do that though)

```
SELECT
sh.stkitm_code,
sh.stkitm_name,
IF(stkhis_type = 'Wastage' OR 
    stkhis_type = 'Stock Out', 
    mis.stkitm_qty - sh.stkhis_qty, 
    mis.stkitm_qty + sh.stkhis_qty)   AS item_onhand,
IF(stkhis_type = 'Stock In', 
    sh.stkhis_qty, 
    0)                                AS item_stockin,
IF(stkhis_type = 'Stock Out', 
    sh.stkhis_qty, 
    0)                                AS item_stockout,
IF(stkhis_type = 'Wastage', 
    sh.stkhis_qty, 
    0)                                AS item_wastage,
sh.created_date
FROM stock_history sh
LEFT JOIN main_item_stock mis ON mis.stkitm_code = sh.stkitm_code
WHERE sh.created_date > "<Oldest date>" 
AND sh.created_date < "<Youngest date>"
```

Which will end up looking like this:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, I have tried your query, for 1st query the stockin,stockout,wastage is correct, but item_onhand return wrong value, for second query I cant run at all, a lot error comes out Unrecognized keyword, Unexpected token.

Comment: I've edited my answer to fix the first issue, I'm not sure of the second

Comment: Actually I'm not sure you can get a sum like that this way, I've edited the answer again to just show the change in items on hand, not the actual items on hand